# Force commit with CRLF

Tags: git, line-endings

How do I configure Git to following behavior:

- Checkout as-is
- Commit as CRLF

Until now I've been using `core.autocrlf=false`, however version control police is now demanding all commits to be in CRLF format. Note that this is a TFS repo I am connecting to through Git locally. I tried configuring it as

```
[core]
    autocrlf=input
    eol=CRLF
```

which is I think what I want, but I get this error on commit `error: core.autocrlf=input conflicts with core.eol=crlf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just unset (remove) `core.autocrlf`:

```
git config --unset core.autocrlf
```

and the error message will go away. It will use CRLF line endings for your files, provided that `core.eol` is set to `crlf`

`core.eol` is meant to override `core.autocrlf`, but due to a bug they seem to conflict.